# How to generate equiprobable numbers with a random generator?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, random

Is it possible to emulate a 2 sided coin flip (50/50) with a random number generator which outputs equiprobably the numbers 1, 2 and 3 ?
If yes, how ?

If not why ?

Is there a theorem?

Can it be expanded to any numbers x ("sides" of the coin) and y (random generator output) ?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you are flipping a coin and you want outputs of 1 2 or 3.  Why not flip the coin twice : on HH you get 1 on HT you get 2 on TH you get 3 and on TT you reflip it twice.  Maybe I am grossly misunderstanding the question?

Comment: @Euler....IS_ALIVE : it's quite the opposite : emulate a coin, have outputs with probability 50%/50%, with a random number genrator which has probability 1/3 , 1/3 , 1/3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, of course. The simplest way to do this is to treat $1$ as heads, $2$ as tails, and try again if you get a $3$.

The same approach works whenever $y>x$. If $y<x$, choose $n$ large enough that $y^n>x$, then generate $n$ numbers at a time and use the above approach with the resulting $n$-tuples.

Comment: Nice, is there an algorithm which takes always the same time to execute ?

Comment: @randy There can't be a bounded solution, because after $n$ random numbers from $1$ to $3$, you get $3^n$ equally likely results, and $3^n$ is odd, so there is no way to divy them up.

Comment: There isn't. This can be shown by looking at the probability of any event based on number of tosses bounded by a constant number $N$.

Comment: What about heads if 1, tails if 2 and alternate between heads and tails when 3 comes up.  This will give the 50/50 split in the long run but  maybe it loses its randomness (but not in a very obvious way).

Comment: @MichaelChernick: It will deviate in a very obvious way: With probability $2/3$ it will give the other value in the next round.

Answer (score 7):

In general you should need to query the $3$-valued generator *fewer* times than the number of bits you want to produce, since the amount of entropy per query is $\log(3)/\log(2)=1.58496...$ bits.  However, since $\log(3)/\log(2)$ is irrational, there's no finite number of queries that can be converted into a fixed number of bits.  The best you can do is keep the rounded-off randomness and save it for later use, as follows:

1. Start with $(x,w)=(0,1/3)$.
2. Let $(x,w)=(x+aw,w/3)$, where $a=0,1,2$ with equal probability (using the $3$-valued generator).
3. Repeat these checks as long as one passes:
   (a) If $x\ge 1/2$, output "$1$", then let $(x,w)=(2x-1,2w)$; or (b) if $x+3w<1/2$, output "$0$", then let $(x,w)=(2x,2w)$.
4. Return to step 2.

What this does is generate the successive ternary digits of a real number in $[0,1)$, and outputs each binary digit of the same real number as soon as it is known for certain.  This is essentially [arithmetic coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding), and of course it can be used for any two bases.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution to the general problem: how to sample with
probability p given a die with b faces.  Illustrated here
with p = 1/pi and b = 6.

Write p in base b: p = 0.152431022133341414...  (Of course, if p is
rational this is a recurring sequence.)

Throw the die to generate a set of random digits in [0, b) = 1 3 5 2 ...
and write as a real number q in base b = 0.1352...

Return q < p.  Typically only 1-2 random digits need to be generated.

Interestingly sampling with probability 1/pi can be done without knowing
the value of pi by using a theorem of Ramanujan.  See

http://randomlib.sf.net/1.6/classRandomLib_1_1InversePiProb.html

and references therein.