# Simulate unfair coin with a fair random generator

Tags: probability, random, simulation

Let's say that I have a random generator that gives me the number $1$ or the number $0$ each with probability $1/2$. Is it possible to use this random generator to simulate the toss of an unfair coin that is "head" with probability $2/3$ and "tails" with probability $1/3$?

My guess is no because no power of $2$ is divisible by $3$. But I don't know if my guess is correct and, even if it is, I don't see how I can use this intuition (that no power of $2$ is divisible by $3$) to prove that this simulation with probabilities exactly $2/3$ and $1/3$ is impossible.

Any help is welcome. (I have found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185570/how-to-generate-equiprobable-numbers-with-a-random-generator) question which may be relevant). Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can simulate every rational probability by omitting some results. For example, to simulate 1/3, you omit HH. Then, the outcomes TH,HT and TT have each probability 1/3.

Comment: @Peter Thanks! If I want my simulation to end after a certain number of steps, then I assume it is impossible?

Comment: Yes, theoretically, the length of a coup is not limited. But in practice, this is no problem, only in 1 out of 4 cases, you have a "zero-coup"

Comment: The usual way is anyway to produce random numbers from $0$ to $1$. In this case, you do not have this "problem".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your random number generator until it produces $1$. The probability that you see no $0$s or an even number of $0$s before the first $1$ is $\frac 2 3$. The probability that you see an odd number of $0$s before the first $1$ is $\frac 1 3$.